# JBoss6 does not persist session

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have configured the solution proposed on http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HAWebSessionsviaDatabasePersistence and others like  configure the Manager in the context.xml using both file and db storage. But in JBoss-6.0.0.Final simply does not work. May be a bug?

I have done several tests and on all of them the sessions are properly stored in the configured persistence. But if I redeploy the application or restart the JBoss server it will ignore the persisted sessions and require me a new login instead of reuse the previous one. I have checked that the SessionID is stored in the session persistence and the browser is sending the correct cookie.

I have attached a test case for JBoss-6.0.0.Final. It is configured as http://community.jboss.org/wiki/HAWebSessionsviaDatabasePersistence

Simply add this line to the file jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/data/hypersonic/localDB.script (You could use your own mysql datasource if you want)

```
CREATE TABLE httpsessions (app VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, fullId VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, creationtime BIGINT NOT NULL,  maxinactive BIGINT NOT NULL, version INT NOT NULL, lastaccess BIGINT NOT NULL,  isnew CHAR(1) NOT NULL, valid CHAR(1) NOT NULL, metadata VARBINARY NULL,  attributes LONGVARBINARY NOT NULL,  CONSTRAINT app_id PRIMARY KEY (app, id))
```

Then, deploy the application and go to localhost:8080/web In the login form enter the credentials: user:password If suecssfull login you will get a 'ok' (see index.html) Then, you can see how the session is stored in the database:

```
$ cat jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/data/hypersonic/localDB.log
```

You will get somethig like that:

```
...
DELETE FROM HTTPSESSIONS WHERE APP='/web' AND ID='vIUYhSZDkw7fjCnEealRFA__'
INSERT INTO HTTPSESSIONS VALUES('/web','vIUYhSZDkw7fjCnEealRFA__','vIUYhSZDkw7fjCnEealRFA__',1351177671379,1800,9,1351178495217,'0...
COMMIT
```

If you redeploy the application using:

```
$ touch jboss-6.0.0.Final/server/default/deploy/test.ear/META-INF/application.xml
```

And then reload your browser on localhost:8080/web, you will be prompted to enter the user/password again, even the sesion id has been stored. You get this behavior too using the native jbossweb.sar/context.xml  configuration.

Anybody can say me if I have lost some configuration or really it is a bug? I have done a lot of permutations between several configurations but always get the same results.

I put a link with the test case because I don't know how to attach it to the forum:

http://kcy.me/bww8

Greetings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've research a bit and I've found why this configuration doesn't work for me:

Session persistence is not useful to maintain the users logged in on redeploy if you are using JASS as a authentication framework. The JAAS principal is not persisted so it will be lost anyway.

This can be solved using a cluster, here it is how to do:

http://corecanarias.blogspot.com.es/2013/03/jaas-persistent-sessions-with-jboss-6.html